# Getting almost there need additional permission popup when tab keep in idle state for few hours

Tags: microsoft-teams

I have created a Microsoft teams custom tab app with bot in team scope. When I popout the tab and keep it in idle state for few hours and then perform any activity, I get the popup "almost there" .
I have not added any SSO authentication code which may ask for this.
This is occurring anonymously.
How do I know from where it is coming from? How to fix this?
Thank you for the help in advance.

This popup is not occurring while accessing the tab.

Comment: Could you please share some code snippets and manifest Json so that we can try it from our end?

Comment: The "Almost there" popup usually appears when there's an issue with authentication or session management. Since you mentioned that you haven't added any Single Sign-On (SSO) authentication code, it's possible that the issue is related to session management or token expiration.
If your app uses tokens for authentication, ensure that the tokens are being refreshed properly. Tokens usually have an expiration time, and if the token expires while the tab is in an idle state, it could cause issues when the user tries to perform an activity.